Nonlinear KKT Optimization Problem
Check whether the 1st-order necessary conditions for
optimality hold at the optimum point (1, 0) of the following NLP:
$$min \; f(x) := -x_1$$
$$s.t. \;g_1(x) := -(1-x_1)^3 + x_2 \leq 0$$
$$g_2(x) := -x_2 \leq 0$$
In my attempted solution I used KKT conditions to find the optimum. For the g1, g2 = 0 case (which I believe is the only feasible one) I get x2=0 and x1=1 from the g2 and g1 solutions. However, I receive a contradiction from the stationarity condition for KKT multipliers as $3v_1(x_1-1)^2=1$ which is false.
What am I doing wrong here? I need to do this with a KKT approach but don't see my error
Edit: As requested here is the KKT system I derived



please list out the KKT system you derived

updated the system

The derivation seems correct. I think this is a special case where regularity condition fails: The optimal solution is not a KKT point.
